# What is 'Panama Papers' Case?

Tags: panama-papers

There is a case known as 'Panama Papers' due to which Pakistan's Prime Minister is being asked by the opposition to resign.

What is this case and from where did it start?

Comment: [This](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2016/apr/03/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-panama-papers) should give you some insight.

Comment: And [this BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-36092356) explains its relevance to what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Panama Papers' refer to the set of documents belonging to Mossack Fonseca, a law firm and a provider of offshore services operating in Panama, that was **leaked in 2015** by an anonymous source.

> **What do they reveal?**
>   The documents show the myriad ways in which the rich can exploit secretive offshore tax regimes. Twelve national leaders are among 143 politicians, their families and close associates from around the world known to have been using offshore tax havens.
>
> <sup>Source: https://www.theguardian.com/news/2016/apr/03/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-panama-papers</sup>

The documents basically contained the personal financial information of wealthy individuals, some of which include world leaders and public officials. It also showed how customers opened offshore accounts and used it as safe havens.

There's [a list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_named_in_the_Panama_Papers) of some of the people who are named in the papers.